# find symmetryNumber on c programming

Tags: c, while-loop, symmetry

This is the code that I want to find symmetryNumber.
Data model should be..

Ex.1) If I give 91, it prints out 19. And Compare. 

If it doesn't match with the input number, it add 91 and 19, 

and output 110. And do it again and again.

Ex.2) If I give 2002, it prints out 2002. 
As it is symmetry number, it does match with the input number. So output would be 2002.

No array, or any other advanced skills.
My homework is to solve this problem with basic grammar and variables.
But I think the logic I made have some mistakes.

When I compile this, it is just going on loops, loops, loops 

but it works fine with one digit. I'm not sure why...

Hope you guys help me out, Thanks!

```
ULong Symmetrize (ULong number) {
    ULong symmetryNumber = 0;
    ULong temp;
    ULong quotient;
    ULong remainder;

    do {
        number = number + symmetryNumber;
        temp = number;
        while (temp = 0) {
            quotient = temp/10;
            remainder = temp%10;
            symmetryNumber = (symmetryNumber * 10) + remainder;
            temp = quotient;
        }
    } while (number != symmetryNumber);

    return symmetryNumber;
}
```

Comment: `=` != `==`. Assignment != equality.

Comment: do you mean that i need to edit 'temp=0' to 'temp==0'? :) yeah, it is another mistake, thanks! but it doesn't work as well after all .....

Comment: If you were to work out an example, you would quickly see the problems (there are, at a minimum, 3 major problems, See my answer below

Answer (score 1):

this is one of the  main problems with the code:

```
while (temp = 0) {
```

which is an assignment.

If you had written it with the literal on the left as:

```
while (0 = temp) {
```

Then the compiler would have caught the error.
In any case the comparison should be:

```
while (temp == 0) { // < note the '==' rather than just '='
```

Suggest correcting that statement

a second major problem with the posted code is this line:

```
} while (number != symmetryNumber);
```

lets say 'number' is 25  then the s...number would be 52 and 25 will NEVER equal52, so the loop continues forever.

This line:

```
number = number + symmetryNumber;
```

is absolutely useless because a value + 0 is still the value.
Suggest removing that statement

The outer do...while statement has no effect other than to make it an infinite loop.
Suggest removing the outer loop

Comment: Probably correct answer, but I disagree with the `while (0 = temp) {` suggestion. This just reverses the natural logic. A good compiler should warn about such things anyways (`gcc` *will* warn, for example, with appropriate warning flags like `-Wall`).